# I wish to click a button in selenium using python. I get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the Button "Assign to Myself"" and I am unable to do it.

Please help, the HTML looks like this.

```
   <input value="Assign To Myself" class="btn" name="assign_to_myself" title="Assign To Myself" 
    type="button" onclick="if (window.invokeOnClickJS_00bo0000000PNX2) 
    window.invokeOnClickJS_00bo0000000PNX2(this); else if 
   (parent.window.invokeOnClickJS_00bo0000000PNX2) 
    parent.window.invokeOnClickJS_00bo0000000PNX2(this); return false" style="">
```

I get an error stating

'list' object has no attribute 'click'

What I am using is

```
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="topButtonRow"]/input[10]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>find_elements</kbd> will return the list of elements and you can't click on the list. Either you have to get specific element using <kbd>find_element</kbd> or use index to get the element from element list.

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="topButtonRow"]/input[10]')` will return the list.
Either change the line to `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="topButtonRow"]/input[10]')` or `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="topButtonRow"]/input[10]')[0]` to click.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark  on the left hand side in my answer.